# What determines whether mixed content issue will be recognized as an error or a warning?

Tags: iframe, microsoft-teams, mixed-content

In my case, I am trying to launch external application (desktop application) from within MS Teams and i am getting the following error which blocks the launch:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://teams.microsoft.com/_#/apps/xxx/sections/yyy' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'somepartner-pc:eyJhcHBUb2tlbiI6IjA0NmMyZmIzYzIyNzQwNjIyMGU1NDg3M2FkNGY1ODJlIiwiYXBwVG9rZW5JZCI6IjFfbXV2bGZoMXAiLCJ1c2VySWQiOiJhZG1pbiIsInBhcnRuZXJJZCI6MTg3MDIzMSwic2VydmljZVVFsdHVyYS5jb20iLCJhcHBIb3N0IjoiaHR0cHM6XC9cL3RlYW1zLnFha21zdGVzdC5kZXYua2FsdHVyYS5jb20iLCJlbnRyeVVSTCI6IlwvbXktbWVkaWEiLCJlbnRyeVVSTF92MiI6IiIsImhvc3RpbmdBcHBUeXBlIjoiVGVhbXMiLCJoYXNoVHlwZSI6IlNIQTI1NiJ9'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

The same process from a different platform (blackboard) results in the same console printout but in the form of a warning and not error which results in the desktop application successful launch.

In both cases it is done from an iframe which reside in another iframe. the internal iframe looks like that:

```
<iframe src="somepartner-pc:eyJhcHBUb2tlbiI6ImYwZjUxY2MyNTcyNTU3MjIzZmY4YTg5NWMwYzZlOWI5IiwiYXBwVG9rZW5JZCI6IjFfZDRscVVSTF92MiI6IiIsImhvc3RpbmdBcHBUeXBlIjoiQmxhY2tib2FyZCIsImhhc2hUeXBlIjoiU0hBMjU2In0=" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></iframe>
```

My question is - what is the difference that makes one case result in a warning and the other with an error and how can i overcome it (or workaround it).

Thanks!

Comment: The reason it’s different from Blackboard is that we enforce security differently. But more to your point... I don’t understand the scenario - you are trying to launch a desktop app (local machine) via a URL? From where, that is what context, message, tab, etc.?

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your quick reply. We developed an app for teams which has a screen where you can download a desktop app for screen recording. If you have that desktop app installed, the link in that iframe should be able to launch it.